# Anaconda Connect to Environment Created from Another Server

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have the following resources:

- Server A with Anaconda installed at D:\Anaconda
- Server B with Anaconda installed at D:\Anaconda
- Network Attached Share mapped to drive E: on Server A and Server B

I created a conda environment on the NAS from Server A. Executing Python scripts from Server A within that environment works.

I would like Server B to be able to execute scripts against the environment on the NAS. The environment doesn't show up when running `conda --info envs`, because it wasn't created from Server B.

How do I use an environment on a NAS to execute scripts on a server that did not create the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the directory above the environment to the conda config of server B.  If the environment is at `E:\conda\envs\shared_env` use:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs E:\conda\envs
```

Given the information below, you need to do some testing from within both servers.

```
from conda.base.context import locate_prefix_by_name
locate_prefix_by_name('<environment name>')
```

Comment: Thank you, James. I used `conda config --system --append envs_dirs E:\Anaconda\envs\my_env` from Server B, but the env is still not visible from Server B when running `conda env list`. Where is the system .condaarc folder located to check if the env was properly appended?

Comment: Found it. The .condaarc file on Server B has `E\Anaconda\envs\my_env` listed under `envs_dirs`. Why is the env not visible?

Comment: It could be read/write permissions. Are you using active directory to manager servers and users?  Can you run `conda activate E:\Anaconda\envs\my_env` to activate the environment from B?

Comment: On B, running that results in `Not a conda environment`. On A, running that works perfectly. I have local admin rights on both servers, and read/write permissions to the NAS.